# Parameterizing labels

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to add a label to a new node in Neo4j using parameters?

For example:

```
CREATE (N){nodeLabel}
```

With parameters:

```
nodeLabel = "Widget"
```

I've attempted to do this but have only seen exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently labels cannot be parameterized. Feel free to file a feature request on https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/new.

Answer (score 1):

In short - no. See also this post on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/neo4j/ExULhn1wRio/6Pxr-R8S29QJ) where I have a poor workaround (for Java/SDN anyway).

Whoo hoo, [issue 2000](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2000) created to request this feature