# Is there a way to pass in a parameter for matching on labels in neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I'm using py2neo and trying to pass a parameter(a label) between methods for matching on but I can't figure out the syntax. In the browser I would use this:

```
MATCH n
where n:`Name`
RETURN n
```

This is my python code, where I'm trying to do  similar match:

```
def similar_noder(a):

try:
    graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService(url)
    query = neo4j.CypherQuery(graph_db, 
    """CYPHER 2.0
        MATCH n      
        where (n:`{z}`)
        RETURN id(n)
        """) 
    result = query.execute(z=a)
    for r in result:           
        label = ", ".join(str(e) for e in (r.values[0]))#label
        print label            
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

In this case, "a" is the label "Name" that I'm trying to pass and match on. I'm trying to find all nodes that have the label name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterizing labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834113/parameterizing-labels)

Comment: @StefanArmbruster well that's a bummer. It looks like this just isn't possible.

Comment: it's not a bummer. A different label might lead to a completely different query plan, therefore it does not make sense to use parameters for labels. You can always parameterize the cypher statement on application side using string concatenation or using a builder for that, e.g. Cypher DSL.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster how would you parameterize the cypher statement on the application side? that might work for me.

Comment: why are you testing the label in the `WHERE` clause like `CYPHER 2.0
        MATCH n      
        where (n:`{z}`)
        RETURN id(n)` instead of simply puting it into the `MATCH` clause like `CYPHER 2.0
        MATCH (n:`{z}`)
        RETURN id(n)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something you can do, when you don't have many nodes to search is to use this:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE {z} IN labels(n)
RETURN n
```

But it won't be fast, as Cypher can't optimize it if it doesn't know the label at compile time.

Comment: It well enough for what I'm trying to do. Thanks!